# how to set the background color of selected row in a custom list?

Tags: android

i am trying to change the background color of the selected row in a listview and i am able to do it.
    But when i am clicking on another row then the background color of the previously selectedrow remains unchanged. I have the position of the previously selected row, Can anybody help me that how can change the background color of previously selected row as it was before??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep track and update the listItems clicked state in your model you can just put the code for displaying `has been clicked-color` in the adapter and then call

`adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();`

Comment: i tried it but it is not giving any proper solution to this problem. Any other help??

Comment: did you update your adapter to display a different color if a model is marked as checked? Do you want the list to display all "checked" items with a different background color or just the one most recently clicked?

Comment: i tried it and it works.but when i scroll the list and then go back to the previous position then the selected row color gone. and also the notifydatasetchanged() works when the scrolling is happend.. So plz clear me out from this query

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be easier if you look at it another way.

Currently, your logic is "if I click on this row, change its color to a special color and change the old row's color back to the original color". However, this doesn't seem to be the logic you *actually* want. Rather, you want the last clicked (aka selected) row to be a different color.

You haven't posted any code, so I don't know if you are implementing your own ListAdapter in this project. That is the approach I would take. Create a class which extends ListAdapter, and create an additional private variable that stores the position of the last selected row. Then in the overriden getView() method, do a quick check

```
if(rowPosition == lastSelectedRowPosition) 
   viewToReturn.setBackgroundColor();
```

If you aren't sure how to make your own list adapter, check out the tutorial at http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2010/12/19/custom-android-listadapter.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity use setOnItemClickListener of Your_List Object.

See Demo Code:

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); // <--- Use color you like here
            //  ^ this v gives current row. 
     }
});
```

This will make background color changed for that row forever.

Comment: That i know but i want to get back the previous background color of the row when any other row is gets selected. please tell me if you have any other solution to this problem..